# Modify value xml tag with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, elementtree

I have this xml:

```
<resources>
    <string name="name1">value1</string>
    <string name="name2">value2</string>
    <string name="name3">value3</string>
    <string name="name4">value4</string>
    <string name="name5">value5</string>
</resources>
```

and I want to change each value of each string tag, I've tried with ElementTree but i can not solve it...

I have this but it doesn't works!

```
tree = ET.parse(archivo_xml)
root = tree.getroot()
        
cadena = root.findall('string')
cadena.text = "something"
```

Comment: I have no experience whatsoever with XML in python but I would guess that `root.findall()` returns a list that you'd need to iterate over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `root.findall()` does return a list which is why that approach doesn't work.

Use `root.iter()` to find all the matching tags with `'string'` instead, then loop over the results and change the text value of each.

```
for cadena in root.iter('string'):
    cadena.text = "something"
```